# NSDateFormatter in an NSTableView with a datasource

Tags: cocoa, timezone, nsdateformatter

I am trying to use the `NSDateFormatter` on a cell in a table view. My table view uses a dataSource not an `NSArrayController`.

For some reason, when I enter a date, the `setObjectValue:forTableColumn...` gets a date with `‑0000` timezone. I set the formatter in IB and I also tried setting in the delegate method `dataCellForTableColumn`.

Why doesn't the `NSDateFormatter` keep the time zone?

Comment: Are you actually setting the time zone on the date formatter?